# Is it possible to interpolate a value to a class name with ng-class?

Tags: angularjs, ng-class, angular1.6

Is it possible to interpolate a value to a class name with `ng-class`?
I'm not even sure whether it's possible in AngularJS 1.6

So for example:

```
<section id=“section-1”>
  <p class=“myclass-1”>help</p>
</section>

<section id=“section-2”>
  <p class=“myclass-2”>help</p>
</section>

<section id=“section-2”>
  <p class=“myclass-2”>help</p>
</section>
```

I tried the following which obviously doesn’t work..

```
<div ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.somethings">
  <section id="section-{{$index}}">
    <p ng-class="{'my class-{{index}}': $ctrl.name==='examplething' && $index==={{index}} }">
      help
    </p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Why mixing interpolation and expressions is bad practice](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#why-mixing-interpolation-and-expressions-is-bad-practice-).

Answer (score 1):

no need to use the interpolation inside the `ng-class` since it is an angular directive.

```
<p class="my" ng-class="{ ($ctrl.name==='examplething' && $index=== index) ? 'class-' + index : ''}" >help</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ng-class` directive needs to use the string form:

```
div ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.somethings">
  <section id="section-{{$index}}">
    <p ng-class="(condition) ? 'myclass-'+$index : '' ">
      help
    </p>
  </section>
</div>
```

From the Docs:

> #### Why mixing interpolation and expressions is bad practice:
>
> - It increases the complexity of the markup
> - There is no guarantee that it works for every directive, because interpolation itself is a directive. If another directive accesses attribute data before interpolation has run, it will get the raw interpolation markup and not data.
> - It impacts performance, as interpolation adds another watcher to the scope.
> - Since this is not recommended usage, we do not test for this, and changes to AngularJS core may break your code.
>
> [— AngularJS Developer Guide - mixing interpolation and expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#why-mixing-interpolation-and-expressions-is-bad-practice-)

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like the below code, also please check [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/q82GwJPoS8jJkwTkAmBj?p=preview) with working example for your given scenario..

**Template:**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in somethings">
  <section id="section-{{$index+1}}">
    <p ng-class="{'myclass-{{$index+1}}': (item.value==='World{{$index+1}}' && $index==={{$index}}) }">help</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.somethings = [{value: 'World1'}, {value: 'World2'}, {value: 'World3'}];
```